# My include menu appears twice drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I have an issue with a menu in Drupal; this is why I need your help.

I want to replace the function in themplate.php

Actually :

```
function mymenu_menu_tree__menu_block__1($vars){ 
return '<div class="bloc-lien-footer">
            <p class="title">Liens</p>
            <ul>'.$vars['tree'].'</ul>
        </div>';}
```

This is what I want to do :

```
function mymenu_menu_tree__menu_block__1($vars){ 
include ('sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/inc/nav.inc.php');}
```

The problem is that when I put my include it appears twice in front.
When I write only text in `<p>` for example it appears once like I want.

How can I fix the double display of my include?

Comment: I guess the function is called twice. You can try **include_once**, but first you should try to understand why the code is being called twice, and if it's not on purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's working now. But like you said i don't know why it's call twice

Comment: Aucune idée, il faudrait mettre des logs...